# Turn off window screen using Matlab function

Tags: windows, matlab

I have a code in which I want to turn off the computer screen using a Matlab function. I did find code that shuts down the computer via `system('shutdown -s')`, but I just need to turn the display of my laptop off. I am using Window 7. Could anyone suggest how?

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to do this.

Comment: This is an additional function where Matlab can detect if the user is not in front of the computer, it will turn the screen off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly OS-specific. Here are a few possibilities:

**Mac OS X:** From OS X 10.9 on, there is the command [`pmset displaysleepnow`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pmset.1.html) which you can call in the terminal. To call this from MATLAB, simply use

```
system('pmset displaysleepnow');
```

**Linux:**
In Linux (I couldn't test that yet though) you can use [`xset dpms`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Power_Management_Signaling) to control the screen. You might have to activate `dpms` first with `xset +dpms`, then you can use

```
system('xset dpms force off');
```

**Windows:** The easiest way to get this to work on Windows is by installing the software [*NirCmd*](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) which allows you to control several Windows properties from the command line. Then turning the screen off is as easy as

```
system('nircmd.exe monitor off');
```

As this requires external software, here's another idea: You can use [`SendMessage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx) to switch the screen off. For that you'll have to create a small C or C++ program. You can either write a separate tool to call via `system`, or write a MEX file to do that. I'd suggest a MEX file like this:

```
#include <windows.h>   // needed for SendMessage
#include <mex.h>       // needed for MEX files

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_MONITORPOWER, 2);
}
```

*Note:* I haven't tested this solution yet, will do that as soon as I have a computer with MATLAB on Windows.

Comment: Hi, because i am new to Matlab i don't really know how to write a MEX file using Matlab and then putting it into my function. Could you teach me more? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the Visual Studio C compiler installed? If no, the suggestion to use *NirCmd* might be the easiest and fastest way to get this to work. Otherwise, you'll have to install Visual Studio, create a `.c` file containing the posted C code and compile it by calling `mex yourFileName.c` in the MATLAB command window.

Comment: I will avoid using mex if that is what you suggested. Thanks for help.